# how to send record to table after click the js link/button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, mysqli

i want to make an like-unlike button below the post. registered user can give like. i have make the button, but i don't have idea how to send a record when user click the button. i guess i need `like` table, so this below is table and it field that i have :

`user` : `id_user`, `username`

`posting` : `id_post`, `id_user`, `content`

`like` : `id_like`, `id_user`, `id_post`

posting page and like button script :

```
<?php
include "database_connection.php";
$query=$dbc->query("select user.username, posting.content FROM posting inner join user on user.id_user = posting.id_user where id_post='$_GET[id]'");
$array= $query->fetch_array()
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="post.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $array['username'];?>
    <?php echo $array['content'];?>
<!--THIS IS LIKE BUTTON-->
  <a class="like-button" href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></a>
<!--LIKE BUTTON END-->
</body>
</html>
```

post.js

```
$(function() {
    $('.like-button').click(function(){
        var obj = $(this);
        if( obj.data('liked') ){
            obj.data('liked', false);
            obj.html('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>');
        }
        else{
            obj.data('liked', true);
            obj.html('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: use ajax. search `$.post`

Comment: i think it's my time to learn ajax..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I've taken the time to create a basic working example for you.

I've included the workings of post.js in an inline script rather than a separate file for simplicity with including a PHP variable inside of the script.

**Your HTML Page**

```
<?php
include "database-connection.php";
$user = 1;// get your accessing user ID (not user id of poster)
$post = $_GET['id'];
// query checks whether user has liked the post or not and returns it as well
$query=$dbc->prepare("
    SELECT `user`.`username`, `posting`.`content`, IFNULL(`like`.`id_like`,0) AS `id_like`
    FROM `posting`
    INNER JOIN `user` ON `user`.`id_user` = `posting`.`id_user`
    LEFT JOIN `like` ON `like`.`id_user` = ? AND `like`.`id_post` = ?
    WHERE `posting`.`id_post`=?");
// bind the parameters to avoid injection
$query->execute(array($user, $post, $post));
$array= $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // previously post.js
            $(function() {
                $('.like-button').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var obj = $(this);

                    // ajax query that returns a JSON object with the result of the request
                    $.getJSON('likes.php',{post:obj.data('post'), user: <?php echo $user; ?>}, function(data){
                        //console.log(data); // uncomment for debugging
                        if(data.error){
                            // query returned error, handle it however you want
                        } else {
                            if (data.like == 1){ // user now likes the post
                                obj.html('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>');
                            } else { // user now doesn't like the post
                                obj.html('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $array['username'];?>
        <?php echo $array['content'];?>
        <!--THIS IS LIKE BUTTON-->
        <?php
        if ($array['id_like']==0){
            // user hasn't liked the post, show thumbs down
            echo '<a class="like-button" href="#" data-post="'.$post.'"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i></a>';
        } else {
            // user has liked the post, show thumbs up
            echo '<a class="like-button" href="#" data-post="'.$post.'"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></a>';
        }
        ?>
        <!--LIKE BUTTON END-->
    </body>
</html>
```

**likes.php (the PHP script)**

```
<?php
include "database-connection.php";
$post = $_GET['post'];
$user = $_GET['user'];
$result = (object) ['like'=>null, 'post'=>$post, 'user'=>$user];
$q = $dbc->prepare("SELECT id_like FROM `like` WHERE id_post=? AND id_user=?");
$q->execute(array($post, $user));
$r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if ($q->rowCount() > 0){
    $like = $r->id_like;
} else {
    $like = 0;
}
if ($like == 1){
    // user likes post, so we unlike it by setting id_like to 0 (for false)
    $like = 0;
    $u = $dbc->prepare("UPDATE `like` SET id_like = 0 WHERE id_post=? AND id_user=?");
} elseif ($q->rowCount()>0) {
    // update because the record exists
    $like = 1;
    $u = $dbc->prepare("UPDATE `like` SET id_like = 1 WHERE id_post=? AND id_user=?");
} else {
    // create the record because it doesn't exist yet
    $like = 1;
    $u = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO `like` (id_like, id_post, id_user) VALUES(1, ?, ?)");
}

if($u->execute(array($post, $user))){
    // update succeeded
    $result->like = $like;
} else{
    // there was an error
    $result->error = 'failed to execute in database';
}
// return the json object to your page
echo json_encode($result);
```

Again, this is just the basics of how this would work. You will have to research logins, sessions, and security for yourself to manage the user who are accessing, posting, and liking the content. But I hope this helps!

Comment: helpfull, now i know how noob i am. but i still don't undestand that script because you using PDO and json. it's mean i must learn about it for now..

Comment: PDO provides methods for querying the database. For reference on that, check out [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php). JSON is just a means of writing an object in a standardized serializable format so it can easily be passed over HTTP. So in the example, the `$result` is just an object that gets passed to your javascript with the information about the database query.

Answer (score 0):

Send the request to PHP page on click of like button and handle it there to update the database.

Comment: how to send request from js script?

Comment: go through the following video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDqBd49sBhk here in basic handling of javascript and sending request to server is taught although its not a like unlike function, instead it is a 5 star rating scale where you can also learn the logic.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to send an Ajax request to the server and then handle in in a PHP script.

Here's a way to do that.

`post.js`:

```
$(function() {
    $('.like-button').click(function(){
        var obj = $(this);
        if( obj.data('liked') ){
            obj.data('liked', false);
            obj.html('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>');
        }
        else{
            obj.data('liked', true);
            obj.html('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>');
        }
        $.post('url/to/your_script.php', {
          action: 'updateLikeStatus', 
          status: obj.data('liked'),
          post_id: obj.data('id') // ID of the object that user "liked"
        });
    });
});
```

You can read more about `jQuery.post()` [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). And [here's](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation on more general `jQuery.ajax()` method.

`your_script.php` (script that deals with Ajax requests) might look something like this:

```
<?php
include "database_connection.php";

if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'updateLikeStatus') {
    $id_user = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $id_post = $_POST['post_id'];

    if ($_POST['status'] === true) {

      // adding "like"
      $query = $dbc->query("
        INSERT INTO like
        (id_user, id_post)
        VALUES ({$id_user}, {$id_post});
      ");
      $query->query();
    } else {

      // removing "like"
      $query = $dbc->query("
        DELETE FROM like 
        WHERE id_user = {$id_user}
        AND id_post = {$id_post};
      ");
      $query->query();
    }
}
```

Note that this code is just an example, you shouldn't use it directly in the production. For one thing, you can't put variables from `$_POST` directly into a MySQL query, because it will create an SQL Injection type vulnerability, allowing people to perform arbitrary queries on your server. One way to avoid it is by using [prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Another problem is that you will need to deal with the user authentication and authorization. I've used `$_SESSION['user_id']` in my example, but it won't work unless you initialize session and populate `user_id` value first. Sessions are required so that one user can't like posts on behalf of another user. You can [read more about sessions here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).